# How do I ask Ubuntu to add package to there PPA?

Tags: apt, ppa

Arch Linux has the following package in there AUR:
https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pulse-secure/
Git Clone URL:  https://aur.archlinux.org/pulse-secure.git
Package Base:   pulse-secure

How do I ask for package in Ubuntu PPA?

Comment: "How do I ask for package in Ubuntu PPA?" you mail the owner of the software? This has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: @Rinzwind at some point, it is the people managing the Ubuntu PPA's, not the developper,  that decide on including software in these PPA's.

Comment: It is for payware. https://www.pulsesecure.net/trynow/client-download/ has a DEB download but you need to register and need a license. Responsibilty is with the license holder. Not Canonical or Ubuntu. So "How do I ask for package in Ubuntu PPA?" is moot.

Comment: @Rinzwind surely in this case, but I answered to the question as asked as asked in the title and in the body, i.e., "How do I ask for package in Ubuntu PPA?"

Comment: PPA's are personal package archives, meaning anyone can create one & put anything they want in them (why you need to be careful with PPA's as the only security involved is via the publisher & person install it (who likely won't know the publisher so it's down the whatever checks they perform themselves)).  Ubuntu doesn't manage the PPAs (they're personal archives)

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask software developer about building deb-package and/or publishing it to https://launchpad.net .

Currently you can install this software by using RPM package mentioned in [PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=pulse-secure) with special [`alien`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/alien.1p.html) utility:

```
sudo apt-get install alien

cd ~/Downloads
wget https://www.rz.uni-osnabrueck.de/fileadmin/user_upload/VPN/Software/ps-pulse-linux-9.1r11.0-b6725-64-bit-installer.rpm
sudo alien --install --scripts ps-pulse-linux-9.1r11.0-b6725-64-bit-installer.rpm
```

Then launch it using PulseUI launcher. Control its `pulsesecure.service` using `systemctl`.

Comment: They have a DEB behind the login page: https://www.pulsesecure.net/trynow/client-download/ Name `ps-pulse-linux-[your-pulse-version]-ubuntu-debian-64-bit-installer.deb`

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has its own set of four official repositories ([1](https://itsfoss.com/ppa-guide/))

- **Main** – Canonical-supported free and open-source software.
- **Universe** – Community-maintained free and open-source software.
- **Restricted** – Proprietary drivers for devices.
- **Multiverse** – Software restricted by copyright or legal issues.

Canonical employees and a wider community build and maintain these repositories as part of the creation process of an Ubuntu release. That community decides what packages are included. All of these packages are subject to quality control and compiled for the specific Ubuntu version to ensure a stable system.

Once these repositories are setup, they are maintained mainly for security updates during the life time of the Ubuntu release. They, therefore, are also quite static. Rarely, new software will be introduced during the life time of a release. New software may eventually make it in subsequent Ubuntu releases after a rather thorough decision process.

In order to cater other needs, such as installing newer versions, or do beta testing, the concept of PPA's, **Personal Package Archives** steps in. See a further discussion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them). Ubuntu provides the platform "[Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/)" that enables software developers to create their own repositories. These PPA's are maintained and tested by developers or volunteers, and are not officially endorsed by Ubuntu.

So you depend on the developer, or other volunteers, for creating a PPA. The more stable, qualitative, well maintained, rather widely used and popular the software, the more likely it is to be considered for inclusion in an official repository one day.